# How to overcome IE7 padding issues?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

IE7 is driving me crazy. I know is a small thing, but I don't know what else to google, and I know I am missing something very small.

```
<div id="spotlightHolder">
<div id="spotlight">
    <div id="spotlightMessage">
        <h1 id="spotlightTitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
        <p id="spotlightDescription">Lorem ipsum dolor, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur massa mi, pharetra vitae luctus at, rutrum posuere quam. Integer pharetra tincidunt vehicula. Vestibulum nec purus id purus sodales hendrerit sit.</p>
        <a id="spotlightBotton" href="#" title="Click here to get our Special"></a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The css for the code above is:

```
div#spotlightHolder
{
    background:url(../images/below-menu-gradient.jpg) repeat-x;
    height:100%;
    padding:34px 0 0 0;
}

div#spotlight
{
    height:325px;
    background-color:#00aff0; /* Sky blue */
    background: rgb(0,175,240) url('../images/spotlight.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}

div#spotlightMessage
{
    width:550px;
    height:210px;
    /*margin:0 0 0 315px;*/
    /*padding:70px 0 0 315px;*/
    /*margin:0;*/
    padding-top:70px;
    padding-left:315px;
    text-align:left;
}

div#spotlightMessage p
{
    font-size:22px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
}

div#spotlightMessage h1#spotlightTitle
{
    color:White;
    font-size:35px;
    margin:0 0 17px 0;
}
```

The outcome of all the above is that in IE7 the text block inside the div id=spotlight is farther right in comparison with FF, Chrome, Safari or even IE8.  Could anyone spot the error?

Thanks, Geo

NOTES: I am using YUI CSS Reset library, since an SO question suggested this for a similar error, but this did not fix the error.

NOTE 2: I am using doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

---

IMPORTANT NOTE:

**By adding margin-right:400px to the div#spotlightMessage on the CSS the IE7 issue was fixed.  Since I don't know why this behavior is happening, I will mark the first person that gives an explanation with votes as the accepted answer. Thanks for all your help.**

Comment: How much farther right? 34px, or something else?

Comment: About 193px, give or take. The 34px on the holder div is for top padding, IE7 is pushing the text further to the right. =(

Comment: Have you specified the doctype in your page?

Comment: It looks alright to me in IE7 Mode of IE8, unless it is not in quirks mode (doctype is HTML4 Strict).
anyway it sounds like a question for doctype.com

Comment: I dont see any difference other than type differences duer to font sets. I also didnt go through the trouble of loading up the YUI reset. I would think that would be the last thing to cause a problem but what happens if you remove it?

Comment: However bad IE may be, it usually doesn't do random things like this (especially 7+), unless there's something fishy about your HTML and/or CSS to begin with. Can you link to the *complete* page so we can have a look?

Comment: Nice you solved this, but I really can't say what the problem is without looking at the full source, as Deceze already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have any spaces/chars before doctpye declaration.

Also, it may be something about margin collapse (but I can't tell you right now, I just woke up and I'm a more like a zombie right now :D )

However, you didn't tell us if the page is valid. You may also have some nested elements out there. So I think the best thing is to put it online and give us the link :)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

The best way to fix an IE only problem (and there are many IE only problems, esp. in 6+7) is using the "feature" of IE which lets you conditionally include style information only for IE.

Described with an example here: http://dustinbrewer.com/css-trick-target-only-ie-with-an-if-statement/

A prior version of my answer pointed out a "quick fix hack" for IE that would just include one style element in IE.  As has been pointed out in the comments there are a lot of reasons not to do it this way, its only positive aspect being that it is quick:

**Prior version of answer follows**

I would use the IE underscore hack to fix this, here is the first link I found about it:

http://dustinbrewer.com/weekly-css-trick-the-ie-underscore-hack/

Basically you put an underscore before a css attribute and only IE6 and IE7 will use that attribute.  So you could do something like `_right -34px` and it would only effect IE pre version 8.

or in this case change it to have

```
  padding-left:315px;
  _padding-left:122px;
```

the first will effect all other browsers and 2nd row will cascade only for IE

Comment: -1 for using a hack. Hacks are only acceptable if its the only way to target a browser which is not the case with IE. You should use conditional comments to wrap the specific `style` block or external `link`.

Comment: One risk of using these hacks is that we'll never know if a future browser will also parse rules hidden by the hack.

Comment: @Marcel ...and if a hack becomes popular and is in widespread use, it may actually hinder the creation of new browsers and/or CSS specs. If the W3C wanted to include a special "underscore syntax" for one reason or another, it probably can't because it would conflict with a popular hack and wreak havoc to many old pages in new browsers that try to follow the new spec. That's more or less how we ended up with the Quirksmode mess.

Comment: If you add this into external file and include via conditional tags, I don't think will be a problem at all :)

Comment: @deceze: Bullshit. The W3C will never include ‘a special underscore syntax’. Quote from http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#vendor-keywords: “An initial dash or underscore is guaranteed never to be used in a property or keyword by any current or future level of CSS.”

Answer (score 0):

On the surface, your CSS seems fine. Would be useful to see all of your CSS, especially that which applies to body, but it seems to be a parent element problem. Try setting a fixed or percentage width for your div#spotlightHolder.

Answer (score 0):

Try Eric Meyer's CSS reset tool instead of wasting your time focusing on IE's quirks.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

And why not assign the 550px width to .spotlightholder so it's inherited?

Answer (score 0):

I really like [blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) to do css reset.

It Makes getting consistent layout cross browser very easy and is fairly widely used.